# Why would a command fail when Make runs it but succeed when I run it?

Tags: makefile, mingw, msys2

I'm trying to build a C++ codebase.  (The code happens to be Cap'n Proto 0.5.3, but I'm seeing this with other projects too.)  I'm building with GCC in MinGW-w64 and running the build in MSYS2.  GCC is 5.2.0.  Make is 4.1.

I run Make, it goes along for a while.  Then it stops because some command it tried to run failed with an error.  OK fair enough.  The error confuses me.  I copy and paste the command from Make's output to the terminal, and try to run it manually, with no changes.  I expect it to fail again in the same way, whereupon I will perhaps tinker with it to explore the problem...  but it succeeds!  (Well, I don't know anything about libtool...  it produces its specified output file, anyway!)

Illustration of the actions described above:

```
MSYS /c/programmingstuff/capnproto-c++-0.5.3
$ make capnp.exe
C:/msys64/usr/bin/sh.exe ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -std=gnu++11 -I./src -I./src -DKJ_HEADER_WARNINGS -DCAPNP_HEADER_WARNINGS -DCAPNP_INCLUDE_DIR='"/usr/local/include"' -mthreads -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mthreads -release 0.5.3 -no-undefined  -o libkj.la -rpath /usr/local/lib src/kj/common.lo src/kj/units.lo src/kj/memory.lo src/kj/refcount.lo src/kj/array.lo src/kj/string.lo src/kj/string-tree.lo src/kj/exception.lo src/kj/debug.lo src/kj/arena.lo src/kj/io.lo src/kj/mutex.lo src/kj/thread.lo src/kj/main.lo src/kj/parse/char.lo
libtool: link: you must specify an output file
libtool: link: Try `libtool --help --mode=link' for more information.
makefile:1405: recipe for target 'libkj.la' failed
make: *** [libkj.la] Error 1

MSYS /c/programmingstuff/capnproto-c++-0.5.3
$ C:/msys64/usr/bin/sh.exe ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -std=gnu++11 -I./src -I./src -DKJ_HEADER_WARNINGS -DCAPNP_HEADER_WARNINGS -DCAPNP_INCLUDE_DIR='"/usr/local/include"' -mthreads -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -mthreads -release 0.5.3 -no-undefined  -o libkj.la -rpath /usr/local/lib src/kj/common.lo src/kj/units.lo src/kj/memory.lo src/kj/refcount.lo src/kj/array.lo src/kj/string.lo src/kj/string-tree.lo src/kj/exception.lo src/kj/debug.lo src/kj/arena.lo src/kj/io.lo src/kj/mutex.lo src/kj/thread.lo src/kj/main.lo src/kj/parse/char.lo
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libkj.a  src/kj/common.o src/kj/units.o src/kj/memory.o src/kj/refcount.o src/kj/array.o src/kj/string.o src/kj/string-tree.o src/kj/exception.o src/kj/debug.o src/kj/arena.o src/kj/io.o src/kj/mutex.o src/kj/thread.o src/kj/main.o src/kj/parse/char.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libkj.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libkj.la" && cp -pR "../libkj.la" "libkj.la" )
```

After this I run Make again and it gets a little further, only to hang in this same way again.  I copy and paste to kickstart it once more.  This cycle repeats until either the project is fully built or a *real* error arises.

I don't think this is a problem with libtool; I've seen the same thing with several g++ commands while I was trying to build something else with this same setup.  Maybe it's something wrong with Make or with my shell?  I don't know.

How can I stop this from happening?  Or, failing that--what's a good way to get further information about what IS happening?  It perplexes me that the same command would fail when run by Make but succeed when run by me.

Comment: Apparently `libtool` does not recognize the `-o libkj.la` option. Did you check your makefile against strange, non printable, characters?

Comment: No.  I did just now, sort of.  It's a huge automatically generated makefile so I just kinda poked around at the command that was failing and ignored the rest.  Everything seemed fine, but no matter how I massaged it, the command still failed.  Then I tried turning the c:/ in the sh.exe path to a /c/, and suddenly the command worked.  It's a stupid Windows-UNIX file path style discrepancy at the root of this, I guess.  One of the various programs in my processing chain was introducing the c:/, and another was choking on it...  or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a stupid hacky answer that seems to have solved at least one instance of the problem, so I will post it here.  It's way better than manually copying and pasting every failing command, anyway.

The problem in this instance seems to have been a Windows-UNIX file path discrepancy, where some of my UNIXy tools wanted paths to start with /c/ (or just /) and others were cool with paths starting with C:/.  I don't know which tools in particular these were.  I just know that this Makefile contained these lines:

```
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
```

...

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
```

which left $(LIBTOOL) expanding to

```
C:/msys64/usr/bin/sh.exe ./libtool
```

for whatever reason.  Apparently the programs involved in my attempts to manually rerun the command (by pasting it into the terminal) were fine with the C:/, but at least one piece of the machinery working under Make was not fine with it.  As a hack I changed the LIBTOOL line to this:

```
LIBTOOL = /bin/sh $(top_builddir)/libtool
```

and that fixed the problem.  I'm mostly okay with that, though a more elegant solution would be preferable.  And I expect that I'll have to manually figure out how to do something like this any other time this happens to me with this set of tools.  :(